# Is it possible to use other java code in my java application without source code?

Tags: java, class

I have a B.class file, and i am writing a class A.java which needs to use methods of B.class.

Is it possible? Cause B is a .class file, i don't have any source code .java file.[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you pls suggest some sample code @Turing85

Comment: No code nedessary, just some classpath configuration.

Comment: But code is giving error, saying B is not present

Comment: ***What*** code is giving an error, and what specific error are you seeing? Please update your question with real code real error messages and with adequate details to make it easier to answer and more helpful to future visitors.

Comment: Updated @Turing85, can you suggest now

Comment: *Nothing* is updated as far as posting your [errors](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors) is concerned

Comment: What else has to be updated, I am facing an error, i have posted the query with the error

Comment: Thanks @user16320675, but I have added the clazz package in the classpath 'path' in env variables. What should I change in the code?

Comment: You shouldn't be using env variables for anything to do with the classpath. In fact, since you're using an IDE, you shouldn't be bothering about your classpath at all. So get rid of that. The only thing you need to do is to make sure you're importing `B` correctly into `A`. `import foo.bar.B;` You need to know what the *real* `foo.bar` is and you can find that out by running `javap B.class` at the command line. It will tell you what package `B` is in

Comment: Actually that's not necessary, though normal. What is essential is that the package be known and imported correctly

Comment: Please [do not post code as pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7877117)

Comment: @user16320675 As you can see both A.java and B.class are in same package i.e `clazz`
I also tried to import in A.java like import `clazz.B`

Comment: *As you can see both A.java and B.class are in same package* You can't. They are in the same *directory*, which might not be the same thing. I told you above how to make sure what the *actual* package is

Answer (score 2):

It appears you're using *IntelliJ*, or *Android Studio*.
If you open *B.class*, it should attempt to decompile it, and provide the source code.

Nevertheless, the file will need to be in the *out* folder.
There is an orange colored icon next to it, it's just above *src* and below *.idea*.

You can *right-click* on *B.class* to display the *context menu*.
From there, select *Refactor*, and then *Move File...*.

Change the path to the *out* directory.